# Debugging node in a per request strategy

Tags: node.js, debugging, express

I'm dealing with Node for quite a while now, and something keeps annoying me on my production environment: debugging!

So I thought about a system that would be as following:

- An error occurs with a certain level or an uncaught one.
- Log a super long stack trace related to the request, containing all function calls AND variable values since the request happened.
- Send that to a service or a simple log file (monitored) that would inform me that an error happened but with a clear idea of the context.

I don't know how to do something like that or if there are some existing stuff out there doing that job.

My strategy for now, long-stack-trace when an error occurs and crash the worker that will be restarted by the cluster parent (only responsible for redirecting HTTP requests and monitor children)

Thanks!